# Jekyll Build Error for hmfaysal-omega-theme

Tags: jekyll

I downloaded the Omega theme and try to start on my MAC:

But i get this error:

`Configuration file: /Users/rname/jekyll/hmfaysal-omega-theme-gh-pages/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/rname/jekyll/hmfaysal-omega-theme-gh-pages
       Destination: /Users/rname/jekyll/hmfaysal-omega-theme-gh-pages/_site
      Generating... 
     Build Warning: Layout 'none' requested in feed.xml does not exist.
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  Operation not permitted @ unlink_internal - /Users/rnagaraj/jekyll/hmfaysal-omega-theme-gh-pages/_site/LICENSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://github.com/hmfaysal/hmfaysal-omega-theme/issues/20) and [this](https://github.com/hmfaysal/hmfaysal-omega-theme/issues/13), try deleting the license file.

Comment: Thank you. Deleting the License file, solved the problem.