# Jekyll Serve Operation Not Permitted

Tags: jekyll, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When attempting to use `jekyll serve`, I'm receiving an Opertion Not Permitted error. This is Jekyll 3.8.6 running under WSL (Ubuntu) on Win 1903 following the [official instructions](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/windows/#installation-via-bash-on-windows-10).

```
setup@VM:/mnt/c/Users/setup/source/contoso.com$ jekyll serve
Configuration file: /mnt/c/Users/setup/source/contoso.com/_config.yml
            Source: /mnt/c/Users/setup/source/contoso.com
       Destination: /mnt/c/Users/setup/source/contoso.com/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
jekyll 3.8.6 | Error:  Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /mnt/c/Users/setup/source/contoso.com/_site/LICENSE.md
```

I don't see any specific ACL issues and `procmon` doesn't show any relevant error -- it shows SUCCESS entries when `ruby` is processing the file. The specified file also appears in the `_site` directory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567029/how-can-i-install-jekyll-on-osx-10-11

Answer (score 0):

From what I have seen operation not permitted errors are related to user rights or ownership

Try running `sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/c/Users/setup/source/contoso.com/`

I have seen strange errors on computers of colleagues and a simple `ls -al` showed that certain folders were owned by *root*. See if this applied to your system as well and try to change / transfer ownership to your user.

Another update, it turns out that **some people solved the issue by the 
 deleting the LICENSE file**. See this hopefully related ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33623551/jekyll-build-error-for-hmfaysal-omega-theme)).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23669373)

Comment: @patel Why not? From what I have seen *operation not permitted* errors are related to user rights or ownership. I have updated my post.

Comment: Original Answer (one Line) was flagged by someone and this endup with in LQA Queue so my comment is suggesting you can give one line answer in comment section, if that's works for OP you can post it as a comment. To avoid this please give answer with explanation as currently